# PHP MySQL Insert Into & On Duplicate Key Problems

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

Is my code/syntax wrong? I'm not sure what is wrong and am new to this. I have created a table in PHPMyAdmin. It has two columns. One is "id" and is the primary key/auto-increment. The other column is "steamname".

This code is supposed to take a person's online name and enter it into the database. If there is already a record, it should update it anyways with the same/latest name.

The name of the table in phpmyAdmin is **names**

```
        <?php
        // Capture person's name from XML file
        $profile = simplexml_load_file('UrlGoesHere.Com/?xml=1', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        echo (string)$profile->steamID;

        //Enter name into databse and overwrite it if same/duplicate
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databaseName");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // Perform queries
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO names (steamname) VALUES ('$profile') ON   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE steamname = VALUES('$profile')");
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

I tested this by manually changing the value of a row in "steamname" within PHPMyAdmin to "woogy" and then running this script to see if it would update that database value... nothing is happening. It should update "woogy" to the proper name.

**-----------Updates---------------**

Hi all. Thank you for the input. I now have my code as follows. Sorry if it's still wrong. I'm learning.

```
            <?php
        $profile = simplexml_load_file('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198006938281/?xml=1', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        echo (string)$profile->steamID;


        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","userHere","passwordHERE","DBName");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // Perform queries
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO names (steamname) VALUES ('$profile') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), steamname = VALUES(steamname)");
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

This is how the database looks before running the script: (woogy should change to Chatyak)

[Click image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IoTd.jpg)

Now, when I run the PHP page, this is what happens to my database.

[How database looks after running script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkkwl.jpg)

Not sure why it didn't update - and also why there is such a huge space?

Comment: You want to use named parameters in your SQL statements..

Comment: You need to include the `id` in the query, as without it the duplicate key is never matched -> `"INSERT INTO names (id, steamname) VALUES ($profile->steamId,'$profile->name') ON   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE steamname = VALUES(steamname)"`. note the `$profile->steamId`/`$profile->name` are guesses as to what your `id` and updated `name` values are.

Comment: @Sean, `ID` is auto-increment. In that case it's not needed in `INSERT` statement. OP's INSERT query is correct.

Comment: @Rahul true, since `id` is auto_increment than it is not needed, but then the issue is there is never a match against the PK, so it will always `INSERT` a new row, and never `UPDATE` a row. Will have to rethink that answer.

Comment: @Sean,  exactly and correct point and that has been addressed well in MySQL Doc.

Comment: Hi Sean and Rahul - please see my updates/edits in the original post. Thank you for the ongoing assistance.

Comment: Commenting on the edit: in your query the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause will have no effect unless you have a duplicate key. Unless you are using a unique index on steamname, which I'm betting you aren't (or if you are you don't want to be) there is no possibility of creating a duplicate key because you aren't explicitly inserting a value for `id` i.e. `id` is still being automatically generated by `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: The extra whitespace absent any other value is probably from your improper use of the `$profile` variable; it's the whitespace contained in whatever element is the parent element within your instance of `SimpleXMLElement`

Answer (score 2):

Right syntax of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` would be like below, you need to mention the column name in `VALUES` like `VALUES(column_name)` instead of `VALUES('$profile')`. Also, you are missing the PK column `ID` in case of `UPDATE`. Cause you want to update the `steamname` for particular `ID` value.

```
INSERT INTO names (steamname) 
VALUES ('$profile') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), steamname = VALUES(steamname)
```

(OR)

```
INSERT INTO names (steamname) 
VALUES ('$profile') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE steamname = VALUES(steamname)
```

Quoted from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If a table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and `INSERT ... UPDATE`
>   inserts a row, the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function returns the
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. If the statement updates a row instead,
>   `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not meaningful. However, you can work around this
>   by using `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`.

Comment: This still just inserts a new row, because it generates a new auto-increment ID value.

Comment: what @BillKarwin wrote.

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID)` is a circle of nothing. The `INSERT INTO names (steamname)` statement will always generate a new `id`, so no update ever takes place, and if it somehow did `LAST_INSERT_ID()` would be meaningless.

Comment: I expounded on what I believe to be wrong with your answer in an edit on my answer, since it would be too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (IODKU) to update instead of inserting a new row unless you try to insert a value that conflicts with an existing primary or unique key column.

Since you're not specifying any value for ID in this INSERT, it will always increment the auto-increment primary key and insert a new row.

If you want the INSERT to replace the steamname for an existing row, you must specify the ID value in your INSERT.

---

Re your first comment:

I looked at your samples. It's not surprising that it created a new row. It generated a new auto-increment ID value because you didn't specify an ID in your INSERT. So it naturally created a new row. It has no way of telling which row you are trying to replace.

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> create table names (id serial primary key, steamname text);

mysql> insert into names (steamname) values ('Woogy') 
  on duplicate key update ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), steamname = VALUES(steamname);
```

Ignore the `ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID)` part, this has no effect. It's a no-op. @Rahul suggested it, but unfortunately he or she is mistaken. I'm going to take out that term in subsequent tests.

So what happens in this INSERT? You specify a value for `steamname`, but no value for `ID`. So MySQL generates a new value for `ID`. That becomes the primary key value for a new row, and that row is inserted with the steamname 'Woogy'.

```
mysql> select * from names;
+----+-----------+
| id | steamname |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Woogy     |
+----+-----------+
```

Next we try to change the name to 'Chatyak':

```
mysql> insert into names (steamname) values ('Chatyak') 
  on duplicate key update steamname = VALUES(steamname);
```

Which row does this apply the change to? The INSERT does not specify an ID value, so MySQL auto-increments another new ID value. That value is the primary key for a new row, and that's the row that gets the steamname 'Chatyak'.

```
mysql> select * from names;
+----+-----------+
| id | steamname |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Woogy     |
|  2 | Chatyak   |
+----+-----------+
```

What this means is that **you can never trigger the ON DUPLICATE KEY part if you let the auto-increment generate a new ID value every time you INSERT.** Every INSERT will result in a new row.

As I said above, ON DUPLICATE KEY does nothing unless you try to insert a value that conflicts with a primary or unique key for a row that already exists in the table. But in this case you aren't conflicting, you're always generating a new ID value. So it inserts a new row.

If you had a UNIQUE KEY constraint on steamname, then that would be another opportunity for triggering ON DUPLICATE KEY. *But it still won't do what you want.*

```
mysql> alter table names add unique key (steamname(20));
```

Then if you try to insert the *same* steamname as one that already exists, it will not insert a new row. It'll update the existing row.

```
mysql> insert into names (steamname) values ('Chatyak') 
  on duplicate key update ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), steamname = VALUES(steamname);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Note it says "0 rows" were inserted by that statement.

But this still doesn't allow you to change an existing steamname. If you specify a new name, it'll just insert a new row. If you specify the name that's already in use, it's a duplicate so it won't insert a new row, but it won't change the name either.

How do you expect the INSERT statement to apply to an existing row if you let it auto-increment a new ID value? Which existing row do you think it should conflict with?

---

Re your second comment:

You don't need a secondary unique key, I'm just trying to show you how IODKU works.

Before thinking about the SQL syntax, you have to think about the logic of the problem. In other words, if you specify a new name, which existing row do you want it to replace?

For example:

```
mysql> insert into names (id, steamname) values (123, 'Chatyak') 
  on duplicate key update steamname = VALUES(steamname);
```

This would work, because if a row exists with ID 123, this INSERT will cause a duplicate key conflict and therefore the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause will be triggered. But where did we get the value 123 in this example? Presumably in your application, you know what id you think you're updating. Is there a variable for that? Does it correspond to the user's session data?

Comment: Hello Bill - I seem to still be stuck. Please see my edits in the original post with pictures.

Comment: Bill... thank you for the tutorial. I think you are trying to show me what ways to think about making the table? I understand that unless an ID value is actually stated within the INSERT statement... then by default a new row will always be created because the primary key has nothing to check a duplicate against correct? So my question is then... what is the correct formula to declare an ID within the insert statement? I tried adding the unique key as you suggested but I'm not sure what it did or how to remove it from my table. Also - why do we need a unique key if we have a primary key?

Comment: Hello Bill. Thank you for your time. I did test your last code there and it does work very well. The webpage that would update this would be PageName.php and I would have a chron that runs it every few hours. The ID would be manually entered as it is only tracking about 30 people or so. The problem I ran into was when I replaced 'Chatyak' with '$profile'. It does work by not creating a new row (since id value is there :) ) however the steamname column is now that big empty space again.... probably related to what the user mentioned up top with my improper use of the variable.

Comment: Yes, that's a separate issue from the SQL issue. You need to extract a single element from the XML, as @user1433150 showed. You should also consider using [trim()](http://php.net/trim) to remove whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Well, I am extracting just the one element because when it printed onto the webpage it does show exactly what I want.. the issue is somewhere in the transfer to the database. The trim should be a separate variable after this line? echo (string)$profile->steamID;

Comment: HTML presentation will hide extra whitespace, so that's not a reliable indicator. You need to create a variable for the string with whitespace trimmed. Read the documentation for trim() and read the examples.

Comment: $name = trim($profile->steamID);    :)   After much frustration.... appears to be working.... changes and replaces well. I do have one more question that I would appreciate your help on, but it may have to have its own question/page on here.

Answer (score 1):

****************************Edit:***************************

In response to the answer provided by @Rahul. This statement:

> ```
> INSERT INTO names (steamname) 
> VALUES ('$profile') 
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), steamname = VALUES(steamname)
> ```

is technically valid but will always affect exactly 0 rows no matter what. Actually there are so many things wrong with it, that it is difficult to enumerate them all (which is the reason for this edit).

The usage of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` given in MySQL docs at the bottom of [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is an example of how to capture the `id` value of a row that has been **updated** i.e **not inserted**, since otherwise `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (with no argument) would return the last **inserted** id, which in the case of an **update** would not be meaningful in terms of the row in question.

So the above statement, if it ever worked — though it can't — would be effectively no different from this statement:

```
INSERT INTO names (steamname) 
VALUES ('$profile') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE steamname = VALUES(steamname)
```

Except that you would also be updating that row's `id` value to the value it already was.

Aside from that, the reason the statement can never work is because the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause will never be evaluated unless there is a **duplicate key**. And the same error that would occur without the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, will occur when we try to update `steamname` to equal the value of `steamname` i.e. the same value that tripped the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause in the first place.

*******************************END OF EDIT*************************************

First: `$profile` is still an instance of `SimpleXMLElement` object when you try to use it in your query. So the `SimpleXMLElement::__toString` method is called, but `SimpleXMLElement::__toString` method **only returns text content from directly inside the first element**, and not text from any descendants. So if you have some element `<steamname>` and some element `<steamID>` nested within the parent element returned by your call to `simplexml_load_file`, their values will not be returned. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php).

Second: when using the `VALUES` function with an `UPDATE` clause, the correct syntax is to refer to a column name/s like so `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE colname = VALUES(some_col_name)`. If you want to use an explicit value the syntax is `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE colname = 'value'`. See [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Third: since you have `id` set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, any rows inserted into the `names` table  without explicitly inserting an `id` value or using a `WHERE` clause to specify an `id` value will create a new row with a new auto incremented `id` value, regardless of whether you use `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or not because **`AUTO_INCREMENT` will ensure that you never generate a duplicate key**.

I think you may be able to make use of mysql's `REPLACE` statement instead. It's the simplest query that works for your described needs.

```
REPLACE INTO `names` (`id`,`steamname`)
VALUES ($id, $steamname)
```

where `$id` is `$profile->steamID`, and `$steamname` is the new(or not new) value for that row's `steamname` column.

The `REPLACE` statement will simply `DELETE` and then `INSERT` where an `id` value already exists. But since you're inserting the same `id` the effect is of updating the value of `steamname` in the row that contains a matching `id` value. **Just be aware that if you have other columns besides `id` and `steamname` in the same table and you don't include their values in the `REPLACE` statement's `VALUES` then those values will be lost.**

Fourth: for debuging these kinds of things its important to **a**) know what values you're actually passing into your query string. **b**) know that the basic query syntax you're using is correct, apart from any specific values you are(or aren't) using with it.

And finally: make things easy on yourself; since you're already using object notation with SimpleXMLElement to access element values, why not use it with mysqli also? Try this. It is **UNTESTED**, but it think it will work for you.

```
  <?php
    // Capture person's name and id from XML file
    $profile = simplexml_load_file('UrlGoesHere.Com/?xml=1', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
      $profile_id = (string)$profile->steamID;
      $profile_name = (string)$profile->steamName;

    //connect to database
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","databaseName");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    //build query
    //IMPROTANT: this will delete other fields(if any)
    //> in the row, unless they are also refilled by this statement
    $q = ("
    REPLACE INTO `names` (`id`,`steamname`)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    ");

    //uncomment to debug query
      //echo "<pre>$q</pre>";

    //uncomment to debug values
      //echo "<pre>profile_name: \n $profile_name</pre>";
      //echo "<pre>profile_id: \n $profile_id</pre>";

    //prepare statement using above query
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);

    //fill in '?'s with actual values
    //first argument is the data types 
    //'i' [integer] 's' [string]
    //follownig aruments fill in '?'s in order
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $profle_id, $profile_name);

    // execute statement
    $stmt->execute();

    //close statement
    $stmt->close();
    //close connection
    $mysqli->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi user - thank you for your input and thought. I will be sure and test this as well. I'm only just starting to learn all of this so your code is a bit confusing to me.  I understand that we make the "replace" into a variable.. and use that variable in a prepared statement. Does stmt mean anything or is that just a random variable you chose to use? I also left a comment on Bill's answer below as well w here his code did work, but replacing 'Chatyak' with '$profile' leaves a giant empty space again... presumably from your reference of me using it improperly. Does this code fix that?

Comment: `$stmt` is a mysqli prepared statement. When we make this call `$mysqli = new mysqli([...]);` an object of class mysqli is returned. An object is basically just a collection of variables and functions that work together because they are all aware of one another. You access those 'members' like so: `$mysqli->memberName`. `$mysqli->prepare($q);` returns another related object with different members e.g. bind_param, execute, close. So, after capturing that object in the `$stmt` variable, we access its members: `$stmt->bind_param()`. You were already using this with `$profile->steamID`

Comment: It seems you are in way over your head. You're going to have to invest some time and understand more of what is happening in your own code, otherwise your chances of getting it to work as desired are pretty remote. Whether or not you use my code, if can't grok points 1-4 then you're pretty much flying blind. I suggest you use the time you would have spent playing *Pin the Tail on the Donkey*, and instead use it to do some studying; you'll get there faster **and** have more to show for it.